# Single Sign on for 2 .aspx sites on 2 different servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, single-sign-on

I have 2 servers with 2 web sites that look exactly the same but contain different forms.
They are linked together in the menu of the sites and the users have no idea that it is actually 2 different servers.
This strange situation is because my company has split all new development off from the old development (by giving me a new server), but still needs access to some of the old forms.
Both use the same LDAP lookup to log in through AD.

the problem is, users must sign into both individually. so they log into one, then immediately log into the second. as you can guess, this is a huge complaint.

I would like to know how to make it so no matter which server they log into, the other will allow them to access its forms.
Both sites are .NET, both servers are using IIS.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably should add how saved logins are currently transmitted to your server(s)

Comment: Looks like it would be stored in the ADAuthCookie. It is domain specific...

Comment: And your two servers have different domains? Maybe it would be best to change that. https://serverfault.com/questions/347689/how-to-share-domain-name-with-multiple-servers 
I came across this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it is marked as outdated but maybe there is helpful information in it

Comment: I added DNS reverse lookup urls that made them look like they had the same domain, changed all the linking urls to the new ones and used the auth cookie for that domain. It works, but the whole plant needs to clear their cookies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete this question for anyone else looking, here is how I solved this issue;

I added DNS reverse lookup urls that made them look like they had the same domain, changed all the linking urls to the new ones and used the auth cookie for that domain.

I also had to turn off IIS encryption and authentications as the two servers did not share this. The cookie does not send plain text so I assume there is still AD encryption.